# What is the probability of missing a file in a replicated distributed file system?

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

I have a cluster of eleven machines each machine having five hard disks. I am using Hadoop distributed file system (HDFS) which takes each file I upload to the cluster and cut it into blocks and then replicate each block three times on different machines. This means I can lose two from the eleven machines without losing any files because blocks can be restored from the third replicas on some other machines.

[image: Eleven machines each with 5 disks]

Recently I moved my cluster and three hard disks from three different machines were damaged while shipping which means there was a chance that some blocks could have been lost if they were replicated on those exact three disks that were damaged. However that didn't happen and no data was lost.

I told my colleagues that I am lucky this didn't happen but then I started to think whether I am really lucky or maybe the chance of this happening was low to begin with.

I have about 120,000 blocks in my file system. So here is my thinking:

Given a block, there are $\binom {11}{3} = 165$ ways to choose three machines to replicate the block. Once we choose the three machines then there are $5 \times 5 \times 5=125$ ways to choose three disks. So in total there are $165 \times 125=20625$ ways to choose three disks to replicate the block.

So the probability of a block going to the three corrupted disks is $\frac{1}{20625} = 0.00004848484 $

What would be the next step from here to find the probability that at least one block form the 120,000 blocks could have been replicated on the three corrupted disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the probability a particular block is on all three damaged disks is $\frac{3}{55}\times \frac{2}{50} \times \frac{1}{45}$ which gives the same $\dfrac{1}{20625}$ you found.

So the probability it is not is $\dfrac{20624}{20625}$.

Assuming blocks are distributed independently of each other (which may be almost the case), that would make the probability that none of the blocks are on all three damaged disks $\left(\dfrac{20624}{20625}\right)^{120000} \approx 0.003$ (this is also about $e^{-120000/20625} )$

So either you were very lucky (though not impossibly so), or something else happened.

Comment: 0.003 made me reconsider what might have happened and found out from the cluster operator that actually one of the disks was damaged before shipping while the system was running which gave it a chance to recover. So only two disks were damaged while shipping which explains why there was no loss. I may say that I am lucky no third disk was damaged from a third machine :)